# Pygame not detecting when a key is pressed (using events)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a snake game and I'm trying to make it turn whenever I press one of the arrow keys. However, for some reason pygame is not detecting when I press them. I tried just the move_snake function on a different program and it worked perfectly, so I think something else it interfering with it. I just can't figure out what.

Important: I was iterating over all the keys using keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() and iterating over keys and the method worked. However, this added two turns into my program every time I pressed a key. Even when I used a flag to prevent that from happening it would still do that, so I had to stop using it. If there's any way to make it stop doing that, I would be delighted to know.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 700

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

snake_len = 2
snakes = []

dirx = 1
diry = 0
turning = False
run = True

turns = {}
turns1 = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Turns(object):
    def __init__(self, xdir, ydir):
        self.xdir = xdir
        self.ydir = ydir

class Body(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, xdir, ydir):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.xdir = xdir
        self.ydir = ydir

def get_body(x, y, w, h, xdir, ydir):
    return Body(x, y, w, h, xdir, ydir)

def add_turn(xdir, ydir):
    return Turns(xdir, ydir)

def turn_snake(snek):
    global dirx, diry, turning

    turn = turns[0]
    snek.dirx = turns[0].xdir
    snek.diry = turns[0].ydir

    tail = get_tail()

    if snek == tail:
        turns.remove(turn)

    turning = False

def get_tail():
    if snakes:
        tail = snakes[-1]
        return tail

def add_snake():
    tail = get_tail()
    if not snakes:
        snek = get_body(400, 350, 10, 10, 1, 0)
        snakes.append(snek)
    else:
        if dirx == 1:
            snek = get_body(tail.x - tail.w, tail.y, tail.w, tail.h, snakes[0].xdir, snakes[0].ydir)
            snakes.append(snek)
        if diry == 1:
            snek = get_body(tail.x, tail.y - tail.h, tail.w, tail.h, snakes[0].xdir, snakes[0].ydir)
            snakes.append(snek)
        if dirx == -1:
            snek = get_body(tail.x + tail.w, tail.y, tail.w, tail.h, snakes[0].xdir, snakes[0].ydir)
            snakes.append(snek)
        if diry == -1:
            snek = get_body(tail.x, tail.y + tail.h, tail.w, tail.h, snakes[0].xdir, snakes[0].ydir)
            snakes.append(snek)

def draw_snake():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for snake in snakes:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (95, 53, 203), (snake.x, snake.y, snake.w, snake.h))

def update_snake():
    for snake in snakes:
        if turns:
            if snake.x == turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y].x and snake.y == turns[0].y:
                turn_snake(snake)
                snake.x += snake.dirx
                snake.y += snake.diry

def move_snake():
    global dirx, diry, turning

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                turns1.append('left')
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                turn = add_turn(1, 0)
                turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                turn = add_turn(0, -1)
                turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                turn = add_turn(0, 1)
                turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.display.quit()

    if len(snakes) < snake_len:
        add_snake()

    update_snake()
    draw_snake()
    move_snake()
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

**Edit:**

Apparently using only one event loop fixed the issue on the main program, but it's still kind of strange. I ran a debug program that ran only the move_snake function and it worked perfectly fine with two event loops.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

true = True
turns = []
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 800))

def move_snake():
    global dirx, diry, turning
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                turns.append('left')
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 turns.append('right')
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                turns.append('up')
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                turns.append('down')

    print(turns)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.display.quit()
    move_snake()
```

This just makes it that I still don't have a good answer for what was happening in the main program... If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful to know. Thanks!

Comment: you should have only one `for event in pygame.event.get()`. Second loop can't get any event because first loop get all events.

Answer (score 2):

You should have only one loop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Second loop can't get any event because first loop gets all events.

So you should rather use `move_snake(event)` with parameter `event` but without `for`-loop and run it inside `for`-loop in main loop:

```
def move_snake(event):
    global dirx, diry, turning

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            turns1.append('left')
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            turn = add_turn(1, 0)
            turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            turn = add_turn(0, -1)
            turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            turn = add_turn(0, 1)
            turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.display.quit()
        move_snake(event) # <-- run it with every event

    if len(snakes) < snake_len:
        add_snake()

    update_snake()
    draw_snake()

    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I was totally aware that you couldn't do what I was doing lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I just checked the test-program I ran with only the move_snake function and it ran perfectly fine with two event loops. I edited my question to show this. Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: it only confirm that you shouldn't use two event loops because sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it doesn't catch keys. You never know in which moment system will send event with pressed key and which loop will catch it.

Comment: when I run your new code and display text instead of appending to list then I see that sometimes it prints text (it catches pressed keys) but in other moments it doesn't print text (it skips pressed keys). All because sometimes I pressed key when program was running first loop and sometimes when it was running second loop. So behavior  of this code is unpredictable. And this is why you should use only one event loop. All programs use only one event loop.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure because I can't check it right now myself, but if you fix the last part of the code like this then it should work:

```
def move_snake(event):
    global dirx, diry, turning

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            turns1.append('left')
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            turn = add_turn(1, 0)
            turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            turn = add_turn(0, -1)
            turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            turn = add_turn(0, 1)
            turns[snakes[0].x, snakes[0].y] = turn

while run:
    ev=pygame.event.wait():

    if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
        pygame.display.quit()

    if len(snakes) < snake_len:
        add_snake()

    update_snake()
    draw_snake()
    move_snake(ev)
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Basically you parse one event at a time in the main loop, and if it's not a QUIT event then you pass it through the move_snake function as an argument to check if it's a KEYDOWN event.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your response. Using only one event loop fixed the issue. However, it's still kind of confusing since the test program I ran using only the move_snake function ran perfectly fine with two event loops. I edited my question to show this. Do you have any idea why this is so?